# EpiServer website logout no longer working

Tags: c#, .net, episerver

On my EPiServer website I can no longer logout. I do have the username dropdown that offers "Logout" as an option, and when I click on it I am taken to `Util/logout.aspx` which displays a logout confirmation and a button to log in again. However when I re-visit the website I am still logged in.

From what I can tell the `".AspNet.ApplicationCookie"` cookie is not being deleted. If I delete it manually in the browser then I am logged out of the website.

Looking at the cookie properties in Chrome I can see that this cookie is being set with the secure flag. But under the SameSite column it is blank, not sure if that is an issue.

I have tried updating all OWIN related nuget packages in Visual Studio without success.

I have tried incorporating the `SameSiteCookieManager` class from this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/owin-samesite without success.

I am at a loss as to what else to try/test/look at.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Owin authentication you need to map the logout URL. Logging out from the CMS UI will only log you out from ASP.NET Identity and/or Membership. Add following in your Owin startup class:

```
app.Map("/util/logout.aspx", map =>
{
    map.Run(ctx =>
    {
        ctx.Authentication.SignOut();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
});
```